# html base tag with different domain from the top domain gives security issue

Tags: security, google-chrome, cross-domain, block, radix

I've a website which displays and edits the contents of a different web pages like adding css codes to them.

It works like this, i use curl to get the contents of webpages then i edit the content and add base tag with href attribute which points the url that i got the contents of it. Then i put the edited content to an iframe on my website. It was working for a year, but yesterday i noticed an error that google chrome shows me the security warning page.

I've tried so many things to fix this problem but  i couldn't fix it. when i use the base tag with different domain from the top domain, it shows the warning page. Do u have any idea how can a pass this problem. I have to use base tag with a different domain from the base tag.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that was google side error :D We contact with them and the problem is fixed :)